# How to insert iso inside option tag in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I have included given code

```
<%= form.collection_select :country_id, available_countries, :id, :name, {}, {class: 'required'} %>
```

which gives me following list ::

```
<select class="required valid" name="order[bill_address_attributes][country_id]" id="order_bill_address_attributes_country_id">
<option value="1">Åland Islands</option>
<option value="2">Albania</option>
<option value="3">Algeria</option>
<option value="4">American Samoa</option>
<option value="5">Andorra</option>
<option value="6">Angola</option>
</select>
```

I need a list like this ::

```
<select class="required valid" name="order[bill_address_attributes][country_id]" id="order_bill_address_attributes_country_id">
<option value="1" iso = "AX">Åland Islands</option>
<option value="2" iso = "AL">Albania</option>
<option value="3" iso = "DZ">Algeria</option>
<option value="4" iso = "AD"  >Andorra</option>
</select>
```

I fetch iso with `available_countries.map(&:iso)`

Please guide me how to insert iso inside option tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f.select :country_id, options_for_select(@countries.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id, { 'data-currency_code' => c.currency_code }] })
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
available_countries.map {|c| [c.name, c.id, {:'iso' => c.iso} ] }
```